# Django - passing variable to 'get_success_url'

Tags: django, django-views

I have an app where two different views are using the same objects / deleteview.

Both are generic listviews displaying a list of the 'Invite' model. One filters a queryset where 'Invite.org = user.profile.org', the other excludes them.

Since the views are so simular and the models are the same, I thought I could use a single (generic) deleteview to manage deleting invites.

```
class InviteDelete(SecCheck, TenantRootedMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Purchases
    menu_id = 'invites'
    template_name = 'tenants/invite_delete.html'

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        return reverse('invite_list_own', args=[self.request.tenant.slug])

    def form_valid(self, *args, **kwargs):
        from django.contrib import messages
        messages.success(self.request, '{} Invite deleted'.format(self.get_object().name))
        return super(InviteDelete, self).form_valid(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        #Make sure that the user if returned to the correct 'tab' in the event of a cancel.
        data = super(InviteDelete, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        data['return_page'] = self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
        return data
```

The 'delete' form has a confirmation page with a 'cancel'  and a 'confirm delete' button. Pretty standard stuff. However, the problem is that I want the user to return to the previous page after a delete. This could either be View/Template A (Invite.org == user.profile.org)  or View/Template B (Invite.org != user.profile.org)

I'm trying to solve the problem with the `self.request.META.get(HTTP_REFERER')` method. THe 'get_context_data'  pases the 'return_page'  value to the template, which than uses that value to generate the correct url for the 'cancel' button. Like so:

```
<div class="panel-footer text-right">
    <a href="{{ return_page }}" class="btn btn-default">{% trans "Cancel" %}</a>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{% trans 'Delete' %}</button>
</div>
```

This works fine, however, I'm having trouble with the 'get_succes_url'  function. 
I tried using `self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')` for the return value, but since the 'get_succes_url' is a redirect it just returns to the delete-confiration-page.

I need to find a way to define the 'previous page' when the class is accessed and then pass that value to the 'get_succes_url'. But all my attempts have failed so far (it seems the functions are not executed in order?)

Does anyone know of a way to pass the correct value?